# ruby narray concatenation

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

Given say 2x3 and mx3 arrays (I have used `NArray`): how to construct a (2+m)x3 array, the concatenation of each. `+` or `<<` do not keep the elements properly aligned.
e.g.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
# should be concatenated as:
# [[1,2,3,1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,5,6,7,8]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify. Your example has 2x3 and 2xm (not mx3)arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
a.zip(b).map{|x, y| x+y}
# => [[1,2,3,1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,5,6,7,8]]
```